# Can't turn git source control provider off for solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Title says it all.  I know how to turn it off and I've done so for every version of VS that has had it.  My experience has always been that it makes VS chug, I don't like all the visual clutter (and it's even worse in VS 2015 with the function annotations!), and in general I much prefer using git bash when I'm ready to start doing git type things.

The issue is that now when I change the Source Control provider to 'None' it prompts and tells me the solution is using a different provider than the one selected and continuing will close the solution.  If you hit yes and reopen the solution the git provider is still enabled for that solution.

I really *really* want this turned off.  I'll go back to VS 2013 if I can't find a solution to this, it's that much of a showstopper for me.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to actually turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the NoGit Visual Studio Extension.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/146b404a-3c91-46ff-932a-fb0f8b826f94